# Oracle - Count groups in group by

Tags: oracle, group-by, pagination

I have the following query:

```
SELECT substr("Timestamp", 1, 16) "Timestamp", "Action", count(*) "Count"
FROM "MyTable" 
WHERE substr("Timestamp", 1, 13) <= substr(CURRENT_DATE, 1, 13)  
GROUP BY substr("Timestamp", 1, 16), "Action"
ORDER BY substr("Timestamp", 1, 16) DESC, "Action"
```

I want to do paging on the group, so that I e.g. get with page 1 and page-size 2 the first 2 groups with the corresponding elements.

I set up a fiddle for a better understanding. Please see: http://rextester.com/GLY48637

How can I get this paging working?

Comment: Thanks for the demo data. What exactly is the output you expect?

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name Please see my solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution for my problem. I can build a "group-index" and skip/take only the elements in the index. See the following script:

```
SELECT *
FROM
(
   SELECT x.*, ceil((rank() over (order by x."Timestamp") +
       count(1) over (partition by x."Timestamp"))/6) as pageindex
   FROM 
   (
      SELECT substr("Timestamp", 1, 16) "Timestamp", "Action", count(*)  "Count"
      FROM "MyTable" 
      WHERE substr("Timestamp", 1, 13) <= substr(CURRENT_DATE, 1, 13)  
      GROUP BY substr("Timestamp", 1, 16), "Action"
      ORDER BY substr("Timestamp", 1, 16) DESC, "Action"
   ) x
)
WHERE pageindex > (:page - 1) * :pageSize and pageIndex <= :page * :pageSize
```

Answer (score 0):

With Oracle 12c you can limit number of rows returned (keyword "FETCH FIRST").

```
select count(*) 
from dba_objects;
  COUNT(*)
----------
     90930

select object_name 
from dba_objects 
order by object_id 
fetch first 5 rows only;

OBJECT_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
C_OBJ#
I_OBJ#
TAB$
CLU$
C_TS#

5 rows selected.
```

You can even do paging with OFFSET.

```
select object_name 
from dba_objects
order by object_id
offset 2 rows
fetch first 6 rows only;

OBJECT_NAME
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
TAB$
CLU$
C_TS#
I_TS#
C_FILE#_BLOCK#
I_FILE#_BLOCK#

6 rows selected.
```

More examples at: https://oracle-base.com/articles/12c/row-limiting-clause-for-top-n-queries-12cr1
rextester.com refused 12c syntax.

Comment: Yes, this works on records themselve. But I want to page the groups, not the single records. Please see my own answer.